# How to define Java function's return type and parameters, using subclass or superclass?

Tags: java, list, generics, inheritance, arraylist

For example, if I have a function like

```
public List<E> sort(ArrayList<E> list) {...}
```

My classmate told me, we should use List as return type because return type should be as broad as possible. His reason here is we can change to return a LinkedList or another type later if we currently return an ArrayList. It increases the flexibility.

But the function parameter we receive should be as narrow as possible. This is because we may need to use some function that only implemented by ArrayList in our sort function.

So my question is this: is there any widely accepted guidelines/best practices that recommend that formal parameters of a function should be as narrow as possible typed? If not, what would be the main arguments against?

=============================================

Just to clarify that.

```
public List<E> sort(ArrayList<E> list) {...}
```

This is just an example, the List and ArrayList could be replaced by any other Super Class and SubClass. Let's assume there are some functions only exist in the SubClass.

```
public <E> SuperClass<E> sort(SubClass<E> object) {...}
```

Comment: What part specific to an ArrayList do you need? `trimToSize` and `ensureCapacity`?

Comment: If you want your code to be general-purpose, you should both return and accept Interfaces rather than concrete classes. However, if you need specific functions from a particular implementation of an interface, then it certainly makes sense to only accept instances of that implementation.

Comment: @luk2302 This is just an example, the List and ArrayList could be replaced by any other Super Class and Sub Class. Let's assume there are some functions only exist in the Sub class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most programmers will agree that a return as broad as possible is a good thing (due to the flexibility factor) you describe.

I believe many will argue that the as-broad-as-possible guideline holds also for parameters as it allows your function to be used from a broader spectrum: if in some place in the code there is a `LinkedList` object that that place will be able to call your method (if it needs to sort) if it were defined with a parameter of type `List`, but it would not be able to call your method if it were defined with a parameter of type `ArrayList`.

So in general, as broad as possible is a good guideline. Of course, it is up to you (as the author of the method) to determine what "broad as possible" mean for you. Specifically, if you could make it broader but with some cost (e.g., a more complicated implementation) you have to decided whether you are willing to accept this additional complexity (higher chances of bugs) in return for the broader applicability.

Answer (score 1):

To apply the generics correctly, you should both accept and return the same interfaces implemented by ArrayList, LinkedList and so on. Don't forget to return a type parameter `<E>`.

```
public <E> List<E> sort(List<E> list) {
    ...
    return list;    
}
```

This method is applicable to all of the List implementations as below (I don't remember them all):

```
List<String> vector = new Vector<>();
List<String> stack = new Stack<>();
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();

List<String> newList1 = new Main().sort(vector);
List<String> newList2 = new Main().sort(stack);
List<String> newList3 = new Main().sort(arrayList);
List<String> newList4 = new Main().sort(linkedList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your classmate should have told you to start with the correct declaration to begin with:

```
public <<E extends Comparable<? super E>>> List<E> sort(List<E> list)
```

because if you want to sort a `List` without passing a `Comparator`, those elements need to be somehow, well, *comparable*.

Then, *generally*, returning a `List` vs `ArrayList`, the choice should be for `List`. But not always. Think of a `Set` vs `SortedSet` for a minute, returning `SortedSet` makes it clear for the caller that the returned `Set` is actually sorted; as opposed to returning a `Set`.